# "Учебные вопросы" in a military context

Tags: перевод

I encountered the phrase "Учебные вопросы" as the title of a section, while reading a Russian military document.

> Учебные вопросы:
>
> 1. Уяснение задачи, оценка обстановки.
> 2. etc...

What is the meaning of this phrase?

Google translate gives the translation as: "Study Questions", but that seems not quite right to me.

Would "Training questions" be more accurate?

Comment: So the point of this hold is clear, is the stackexchange Russian Language site not to be used for translation questions going from Russian to English?

Comment: well, it's subtle issue since translation can be interpreted pretty wide - understanding of meaning can be treated as translation. But in you case you're clearly asking about what is the English analogue of this Russian word/phrase - and it's offtopic. But! The contrary is OK btw )

Comment: I have edited the question to bring it in line with the community purposes. It is clear to me that the topic starter is in fact asking for help to understand the meaning of the phrase. 
I suggest the question be re-opened.

Comment: I will never understand these *rules*.  Some questions are closed, others are answered. Can't you understand that any question about the meaning involves translation because you use English as a working language?

Comment: @V.V.: I can't agree more.

Comment: @iAndelin: I cannot figure out how to vote your question off hold.
In a textbook such a phrase would mean **Revision questions**.

Comment: Besides,  It's nonsense to ask a meaning or a translation of a Russian word on ELU, btw, some  Eng-Rus translations were accepted here, but they could be answered and are usually answered on ELL with Eng-Eng transforming. There would be no misunderstanding if you did the same.

Comment: @AviGordon There's a word "reopen " under the question, but you need four voices if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40841/discussion-between-avi-gordon-and-v-v).

Comment: @iAndelin thank you for being supportive and editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Russian military officialese.

Your excerpt is apparently a part of a document (*план-конспект*) describing a training session and defining its goals, steps and methods.

In this context, *учебный вопрос* just means "topic": something the trainees are going to learn during this session.

*Уяснение задачи* is something like "objective clarification" (for the lack of a better term; I'm not familiar with English military jargon).

This is a skill of reading and processing orders received down the chain of command, understanding what exactly does and what does not the commander want from you and your regiment.

*Оценка обстановки* is "situation assessment": where you are, what do you have, and how can you use this to complete your objective.

These two skills are what the trainees are going to learn and what the whole session is all about.

Comment: I little correction: "Уяснение" is better translated as "understanding", while "пояснение" or "разъяснение" would be "clarification".

Comment: @C-F: I'm sure there is a proper word for this in English military lingo, which I, unfortunately, don't know (and said as much in my answer). That said, "clarification" is not necessarily something one person does to another, as seen in e.g. "I need to clarify my thoughts". A more precise translation, I think, would be "grasping the objective" or "getting hang of the objective", but I went with "clarification" because it has the same etymology as _уяснить_.